# Silent install an Installsheild that contains an MSI in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have an executable Installshield setup file that I need to install silently.  It appears to call an MSI file as MSIEXEC is launched during installation.  I've tried this in powershell:

```
Start-Process "C:\temp\mysetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/s /v /qn" -Wait
```

However that launches the GUI.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  I've searched and searched and this seems to be what all the cool kids are doing but it refuses to work for me.  Many thanks.  :)

Comment: install-package has a msi provider -- no idea bout argument passing tho. also you can find tons of stuff on Choco

Comment: Does `mysetup.exe` provide any parameters? What does `mysetup.exe /?` show?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ["Universal Silent Switch Finder" (ussf)](http://deployhappiness.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/ussf.zip) to find and confirm the switch usage.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - was just a syntax issue:

ORIGINAL:

```
Start-Process "C:\temp\mysetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/s /v /qn" -Wait
```

WORKING:

```
Start-Process "C:\temp\mysetup.exe" -ArgumentList '/s','/v/qn' -Wait
```

Thanks for the advice!